# how properly mock multiple useSelector hooks

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

my component has multiple selectors:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
...
const data1 = useSelector(xxxxx)
const data2 = useSelector(yyyyy)
```

How properly mock each in test file?

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    useSelector: jest.fn()
}))
....
useSelector.mockImplementation(() => ({
   dataready: true
}))
```

which selector it's really mocking in this case?

Comment: In that case it will mock both `useSelector`s your code is using.

Comment: how would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mock the selector. You want to test the integration between Redux and React components, not the Redux implementation of selectors. If you use `react-testing-library` it's pretty simple to hijack the `render()` method and implement your store using a Redux Provider component. Here are the docs for [setting up a reusable render function](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#setting-up-a-reusable-test-render-function).

Here's your test re-written with the user in mind:

```js
import { renderWithProviders } from '../../test-utils' // <-- Hijacked render

// Explanation of behavior
it('displays data when ready', { 
  renderWithProviders(<YourComponent />, { 
    preloadedState: {
      someSlice: {
        dataready: true // <-- Pass data for selector in store slice
      }
    }
  })

  // Check that something shows based on selector
  expect(screen.getByTestId('some-testId')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Comment: Not sure why this is accepted answer, as usually you use useSelector on functional component which generally are not connected.

Comment: @mihkelo what happens if you attempt to render a functional component without the Redux provider? It throws errors. If you want a pure, functional component you probably wouldn’t use useSelector().

Comment: This is normally the right answer, you would normally want to provide state to your component via render function, then check on what is returned by render, its not always the case though. You may want to spy on the useDispatch or (less common selector) to check if the dispatch has been called. Then have tests on the reducer / saga.

Comment: @Jeremy Don't mock Redux internals my guy. Your tests will become extremely brittle. Also, don't use sagas, use `extraReducers` in @redux/toolkit or thunks.

Comment: @tonyg interesting, hadn't paid any attention to extraReducers, they are still sync though if my 5mins of reading is right? We have redux-saga and generators for side effects. If your unit testing its ok to check that the dispatch is called i.e. its an outgoing message from your component, not bad to check a message is sent and what it consists of - could also check that the message updates state, but can't recall why i couldn't do at at the time.

Comment: If you want something that does async side effects, [createAsyncThunk()](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) is pretty rad. It provides out of the box statuses `pending/error/fulfilled` that you can then use in `extraReducers()`. I'm guessing it's async because there's API endpoints? I would also include `msw` to stub out the endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as redux from 'react-redux';
...
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest
      .spyOn(redux, 'useSelector')
      .mockReturnValueOnce(xxxx)
      .mockReturnValueOnce(yyyy);
  });
```

Comment: Don't 'think this works. Can't change useSelector / useDispatch.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to do something like this, to get your spy, and then check on what it is called with and mockImplementation to prevent async if thats an issue for you, i'd suggest you provide state via the render function, rather than mock a selector implementation though.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const reactRedux = { useDispatch, useSelector };
const useDispatchMock = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, 'useDispatch');
```